# pandas dynamic cross join according to group min max

Tags: python, pandas

here is my data

```
data = [
 {'shape': 'circle', 'height': 5},
 {'shape': 'circle', 'height': 2},
 {'shape': 'square', 'height': 6}
]
```

I would like to fill in for each shape the missing height for each shape in range,
in the above example 
for 'circle' range is 2-5, 
for 'square' range is 6,

the result will be:

```
data = [
 {'shape': 'circle', 'height': 2},
 {'shape': 'circle', 'height': 3},
 {'shape': 'circle', 'height': 4},
 {'shape': 'circle', 'height': 5},
 {'shape': 'square', 'height': 6}
]
```

Is there a way using pandas for this, using something like cross join, **without using for loops on the dataframe**? 
this is my code I tried, which has a problem- (see at the end)

```
    from itertools import product

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    # get missing values
    min_height = df['height'].min()
    max_height = df['height'].max()
    all_heights = list(range(min_height, max_height + 1))

    # create full values df
    full_shape_list_df = pd.DataFrame(
        list(product(list(df['shape'].unique()), all_heights)),
        columns=['shape', 'height']
    )

    # merge with existing df
    df = pd.merge(
        df,
        full_shape_list_df,
        how='outer',
        on=['shape', 'height']
    ).drop_duplicates().sort_values(['shape', 'height'])
```

the problem with this solution that the range is 2-6 for **all** shapes, the results is:

```
[{'shape': 'circle', 'height': 2},
 {'shape': 'circle', 'height': 3},
 {'shape': 'circle', 'height': 4},
 {'shape': 'circle', 'height': 5},
 {'shape': 'circle', 'height': 6},
 {'shape': 'square', 'height': 2},
 {'shape': 'square', 'height': 3},
 {'shape': 'square', 'height': 4},
 {'shape': 'square', 'height': 5},
 {'shape': 'square', 'height': 6}]
```

maybe I can try aggregating by shape - and then doing a cross join?

```
shape_height_min_max_df = df.groupby('shape').height.agg(['min', 'max'])
# now do here some cross join (avoid for loops) - how?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use a very similar approach except [`groupby aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) into a `list` with range values from the [`min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.min.html) to the [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html) values per group then [`DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas-dataframe-explode) back into rows:

```
df = df.groupby('shape', as_index=False)['height'].agg(
    lambda x: np.arange(x.min(), x.max() + 1).tolist()
).explode('height', ignore_index=True)
```

`df`:

```
    shape height
0  circle      2
1  circle      3
2  circle      4
3  circle      5
4  square      6
```

DataFrame and imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'shape': ['circle', 'circle', 'square'],
                   'height': [5, 2, 6]})
```

---

Edit to include width column:

We can also create a [`MultiIndex.from_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_frame.html) and use this to [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) the dataframe:

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
    df.groupby('shape', as_index=False)['height'].agg(
        lambda x: np.arange(x.min(), x.max() + 1).tolist()
    ).explode('height', ignore_index=True)
)

df = df.set_index(['shape', 'height']).reindex(midx, fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

```
    shape  height  width
0  circle       2      3
1  circle       3      0
2  circle       4      0
3  circle       5      4
4  square       6      2
```

DataFrame and imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'shape': ['circle', 'circle', 'square'],
                   'height': [5, 2, 6],
                   'width': [4, 3, 2]})
```

---

Explanation:

1. Aggregate values into list containing range from `min` to `max` (+ 1 since upperbound is non-inclusive):

```
df.groupby('shape', as_index=False)['height'].agg(
    lambda x: np.arange(x.min(), x.max() + 1).tolist()
)
```

```
    shape        height
0  circle  [2, 3, 4, 5]
1  square           [6]
```

2. `explode` the list values into rows:

```
df.groupby('shape', as_index=False)['height'].agg(
    lambda x: np.arange(x.min(), x.max() + 1).tolist()
).explode('height', ignore_index=True)
```

```
    shape height
0  circle      2
1  circle      3
2  circle      4
3  circle      5
4  square      6
```

Comment: thanks for you answer! what if I have another column 'width' and in the result I would like to include the 'width' column, and set 0 for the new rows? (I can edit my question if it's not clear)

Comment: Updated to include reindexing instead of just exploding. See the middle blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set heigth as index, and reindex using a range between min and max:

```
def reindex_fill(d):
    return (d.set_index('height')
             .reindex(range(d['height'].min(),
                            d['height'].max()+1)
                     )
             .ffill()
             .reset_index()
           )
    
df.groupby('shape', as_index=False).apply(reindex_fill).droplevel(0)
```

output:

```
   height   shape
0       2  circle
1       3  circle
2       4  circle
3       5  circle
0       6  square
```

*NB. this will move the `height` as the first column, but this can be fixed if a problem*